# How to set busybox vi auto wrap when a line too long?

Tags: docker, vi, busybox, alpine-linux

I use command line in docker,the os is alpine linux, when use vi command,if a line is too long,it can't auto wrap, so the end of the line cannot be displayed.

I tried several settings, such as: set columns=,set wrap,stty columns... all settings are not in effect.

Does anyone know how to set it up? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

busyBox is not support Wrapping line .

see: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/BusyBox_vi
"No wrapping of long lines. Long lines are displayed via side-scrolling."

Comment: Funny that they list that under the "Some may consider these enhancements" section.